# How to change web service URL dynamically or easily?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services, asmx

I have few web service references in an asp.net vb web application .net 4 and using VS2010.
One of them is WCF service (I think as it has .svc at the end) and two of them is .asmx services.
I have to change them quite often to change to different environment such as development, test, production. What i normally do is right click on the service reference (.svcmap file) and choose configure service reference. It will update the service reference and web.config. It will also override binding setting such as maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" that i have to put in web.config every time I change the URL.

I am wondering if there is an easier way to change the URL than what I am currently doing. I have seen similar posts on SO about setting URL Behaviour = Dynamic but I don't have that option in mine and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

With .Net 4, it looks like the proxy class has a constructor that takes some useful parameters. Try instantiating your proxy class like this:

```
MyService.FooSoapClient foo=new MyService.FooSoapClient("MyServiceSoap",myURL);
```

The MyServiceSoap name comes from the App.config file. Look for **name** property in the `<client> <endpoint ... name="MyServiceSoap" />` tag.